# concatenating string and int for filename in cpp

Tags: c++, string, loops, concatenation

As a newbie to C++, I have looked at [*C++ concatenate string and int*](/questions/191757/c-concatenate-string-and-int), but my requirements are not quite the same.

I have a sample code such as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
std::string name = "John"; int age = 21;
std::string result;
std::ofstream myfile;
char numstr[21]; 
sprintf(numstr, "%d", age);
result = name + numstr;
myfile.open(result);
myfile << "HELLO THERE";
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

The string and int concatenation works generally but not when I want it to be a filename.

So basically, I want the filename to be the combination of string and integer. This is not working for me and I am getting the error

> no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka
>   std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’

I want this logic to be used in a for loop where

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
if(i%20==0) {
  result = name + i;
  myfile.open(result);
  myfile << "The value is:" << i;
  myfile.close(); }
}
```

So, basically for every 20th iteration, I need this "The value is" to be printed in a new file which will have the name John20, John40 and so on.. So, for 100 iterations, I should have 5 files.

Comment: maybe try more C++-like way of converting the int to string(std::to_string)

Comment: Make a _minimal_ testcase. If you had bothered, you'd know that this has nothing whatsoever to do with concatenating. You just didn't pass the right argument to the stream constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The string and int concatenation works generally but not when I want it to be a filename.

It has nothing to do with concatenating strings. Your compiler doesn't support C++11, which means you cannot pass an `std::string` as argument to `std::ofstream::open`. You need a pointer to a null terminated string. Luckily, `std::string::c_str()` gives you that:

```
myfile.open(result.c_str());
```

Note that you can instantiate the stream directly:

```
myfile(result.c_str()); // opens file
```

As for the loop version, see one of the many duplicates that deal with concatenating ints and strings.

Answer (score 3):

The question you cited is highly relevant to your string concatenation problem.  I suggest using the [C++11 solution](/a/11860411/1157100) if possible:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    const std::string name = "John";
    std::ofstream myfile;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 20) {
        myfile.open(name + std::to_string(i));
        myfile << "The value is:" << i;
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

Or the [`stringstream` solution](/a/191780/1157100) for compatibility:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    const std::string name = "John";
    std::ofstream myfile;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 20) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << name << i;
        myfile.open(ss.str().c_str());
        myfile << "The value is:" << i;
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

In addition, you should:

- Eliminate stray includes `<iostream>` and `<stdio.h>`
- Eliminate `using namespace std;`, which is bad practice in general — and you don't even need it.
- Simplify the loop
- Mark the prefix as `const`

(You *could* compose the filename using `sprintf(numstr, "%s%d", name.c_str(), i)`, but that would just be very poor C++ code.)

Comment: first time I hear of `std::to_string`!

Answer (score 0):

If we first start by looking at the loop, we can choose to start counting from 1 instead of 0, that way your first file will be `name+20`, and we stop counting before `i` hits 101, that way your last file will be `name+100`. 
We also need to add `.txt` to the string, in order to make a text file.
 You can pass these arguments to a function as references or reference to const if you won't change the data(like name for example). Then we need to convert `i` to a string, if your compiler supports c++11 you can use `std::to_string()`. I have chosen to create an ostringstream object, and to store the string returned from member function `.str()`. 
This is your loop edited:

```
for(int i=1;i != 101;++i) {
        if(i%20==0) {
            ostringstream temp;            // use a string stream to convert int...
            temp << i;
            str = temp.str();              // ...to str
            result = name + str + ending;  // concatenating strings.
            myfile.open(result);
            myfile << "The value is:" << i;
            myfile.close();
        }
}
```

Now it would be a good idea to place this loop inside of a function and pass all the relevant arguments to it. Here is a full working [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a65a4e24385f0cd6)

Output files are: John20.txt, John40.txt, John60.txt, John80.txt, John100.txt

There are other ways to accomplish this, but this should give you a general idea. Hope it helps.